# jquery generate modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I would like to display a Modal box. Is this possible?
I have code below showing how I normally generate textboxes etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 1;

$(".thing").click(function GenerateModal () {  

var newModal = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'myModal' + counter).attr("class", 'modal hide fade').attr("tabindex", '-1').attr("role", 'dialog').attr("aria-labelledby", 'myModalLabel').attr("aria-hidden", 'true');


newModal.after().html('<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p><img src="img/werk/logo.jpg" class="pull-right" alt=""><p>One fine body…</p></div>');

//Excecute new modal?//

counter++;
});
});
```

Comment: Rather than removing the question, please tell us how you solved the problem by posting your own answer using the "Answer Your Question" button below. This will help others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/04/techniques-for-creating-modal-windows/. To create a modal dialog a div-"layer" covering the whole screen is used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modal Window</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var newModal;

        function executeModal() {
            $("#blind").attr("z-index", 9999).show();
            $("#modalDivContainer").append(newModal).show();
        }

        function closeModal(count) {
            $("#modalDivContainer").hide();
            $("#myModal" + count).remove();
            $("#blind").attr("z-index", 0).hide();
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var counter = 1;

            $(".thing").click(function GenerateModal() {
                newModal = $(document.createElement('div'))
                        .attr("id", 'myModal' + counter).attr("class", 'modal hide fade').attr("tabindex", '-1').attr("role", 'dialog').attr("aria-labelledby", 'myModalLabel').attr("aria-hidden", 'true');
                newModal.after().html('<div class="modal-header"><button onclick="closeModal(' + counter + ')" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p><img src="img/werk/logo.jpg" class="pull-right" alt=""><p>One fine body…</p></div>');
                executeModal();
                counter++;
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .blind
        {
            z-index:0;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display: none;
            background-color:#555;
        }
        .modalDivContainer {
            z-index: 10000;
            position:absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width:400px;
            height:300px;
            margin-left:-200px;
            margin-top:-150px;
            display: none;
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="blind" id="blind"></div>
    <div class="modalDivContainer" id="modalDivContainer"></div>
    <button class="thing">thing</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will keep me going ;)

Comment: I am happy that i could help you, i will also be happy about an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what mean with: "Execute new modal?"

But here some hints:

Use this:

```
$(".thing").click(function() {
```

or

```
function GenerateModal () {...}
$(".thing").click(GenerateModal);
```

This is also possible:

```
var newModal = $('<div attr="var" attr="var" attr="var" />')
```

or also .attr() as Array

```
var newModal = $('<div/>').attr({"attr":"var",...})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :p I got it already :p I post faster than I think